# How would I deal with the unhandled exception that is raised from s3.getObject()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to get an image from S3 using this backend function below:

```
exports.getImage = function (req, res) {
    let request = req.query;
    let key = request.key;
    let bucket = request.bucket;
    if (!key) {
        return res.status(400).end("missing key");
    }
    if (!bucket) {
        return res.status(400).end("missing bucket name");
    }
    let options = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
    };

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', content_map['jpg']);

    let nimage = null;

    try {
        nimage = await s3.getObject(options).createReadStream().pipe(res);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

As one can see, there are measures against the lack of a `key` or a `bucket` within the request, a `status 400` is sent back. However, I want to handle situations where the wrong `key` or the the wrong `bucket` is specified. The situation where the wrong key is added to the request in erroneously handled in the code above.

I also handled it using the code below, but did not end up getting any results:

```
s3.getObject(options, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).end(err);
    }
}).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

---

The error that pops up is:

```
4:15:32 PM - error: caught an unhandled exception! NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```